# How to check the pattern of a column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which has some id's. I want to check the pattern of those column values.

Here is how the column looks like-
id: {ASDH12HK,GHST67KH,AGSH90IL,THKI86LK}

I want to to write a code that can distinguish characters and numerics in the pattern above and display an output like 'SSSS99SS' as the pattern of the column above where 'S' represents a character and '9' represents a numeric.This dataset is a large dataset so I can't predefine the position the characters and numeric will be in.I want the code to calculate the position of the characters and numerics. I am new to python so any leads will be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
my_string = "ASDH12HK"

def decode_pattern(my_string):
    my_string = ''.join(str(9) if s.isdigit() else s for s in my_string)
    my_string = ''.join('S' if s.isalpha() else s for s in my_string)
    return my_string

decode_pattern(my_string)
```

Output:

```
'SSSS99SS'
```

You can apply this to the column in your dataframe as well as below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['ASDH12HK','GHST67KH','AGSH90IL','THKI86LK', 'SOMEPATTERN123'], columns=['id'])
df['pattern'] = df['id'].map(decode_pattern)
df
```

Output:

```
id  pattern
0   ASDH12HK    SSSS99SS
1   GHST67KH    SSSS99SS
2   AGSH90IL    SSSS99SS
3   THKI86LK    SSSS99SS
4   SOMEPATTERN123  SSSSSSSSSSS999
```

Comment: This is what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular experssion:

```
 st = "SSSS99SSSS"
 a = re.match("[A-Za-z]{4}[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z]{4}", st)
```

It will return a match if the string starting with 4 Char followed by 2 numeric and again 4 char

So you can use this in your df to filter the df

Comment: I am using a large dataset where I can't predefine the position where a character and numeric will be in. Is there a generic way to do it?

Comment: But the case is you nee to fined a pattern

Comment: oky you mean 6 string and 2 numeric..?(as per you question)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `findall()` from the re module:

```
import re
text = "ASDH12HK,GHST67KH,AGSH90IL,THKI86LK"
result = re.findall("[A-Za-z]{4}[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z]{2}", text)
print(result)
```